# Add the check box values PHP, MySQL and alertbox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Following is my table structure :-

```
Name    Marks
A   12
B   41
C   13
D   24
E   91
F   89
G   87
```

table name is "login". My code is as follows :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name='checkbox1[]' method="post" action="student_slected.php" >       
<label class="cb1" for="checkbox1"> </label>
<input type="hidden" name="checkbox1[]"  id="check" value="null">
<b><h3>Select students :-</h3></b>
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root1") or die (mysql_error ());

    mysql_select_db("my_db") or die(mysql_error());

    $strSQL = "SELECT Name FROM login ORDER BY Name";

    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) 
    {
    $man = $row['Name'];
    echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$man.'" name="checkbox1[]" />'; 
    echo $man;
    echo "<br>";
    }
    mysql_close();
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" style= "height:40px; width:150px; font-weight: bold; font-size:10;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want an alert box using JavaScript when user checks the Name list the sum of marks should not exceed 100. i.e if user selects A,B,D and E the sum exceeds 100 , then a alert message should be displayed stating "you cannot exceed summation of marks 100". Please help me with the necessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use purely JavaScript without any additional libraries then you should put **onchange** event on your checkboxes. That activates a function that handles checking and unchecking events. Also, you should add something that helps your JavaScript code to detect checkboxes that should be considered when calculating the sum. Here, I've put a class called **chkbox**:

```
<input type="checkbox" value = "50" class="chkbox" onchange="jsFunction()" />
```

Now, for your JavaScript function:

```
function jsFunction(element)
{
    var sum = 0,i;
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('chkbox');

    for(i = 0;i<elements.length;i++)
    {
        if(elements[i].checked)
        {
            sum += parseInt(elements[i].value);
        }
    }

    if(sum > 100)
    {
        alert("100 exceeded");
        element.checked = false;
    }
}
```

This code just takes all elements that have the appropriate class, checks if that elements property called **checked** is true, and if it is adds its value to the sum.

In order to have Marks data available you should alter your SQL query:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT Name,Marks FROM login ORDER BY Name";
```

When creating checkboxes in php you should set checkbox value to Marks value of the current row:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" value="'.$row['Marks'].'" class="chkbox"  name="checkbox1[]" onchange="jsFunction(this)" />';
```

This way you have values of Marks set as the value properties of checkboxes.

Comment: but values are stored in a mysql table.. will this work when I select Name and the corresponding marks get added when the check box is ticked and display an alert box when the selection exceeds summation of 100 marks.

Comment: The idea is to fetch both Name and Marks columns and put Marks value as the value of the checkbox.

Comment: How do I fetch that data and store as a Input in the checkbox ? I am only printing the Name column in the while loop. Now how do I fetch the Marks ?

Comment: I have edited my answer with details on how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! @user2679265  One last thing, is there any way by which I can uncheck the last option which is checked before the alert message appears. i.e. the option which is exceeding the sum by 100 ?

Comment: Suppose there is any there is a 3rd column having the Unit, I want the user to ensure that he selects maximum of 2 people from each unit. Can you this be added in the existing code ? There are only 3 units. @user2679265